# How to send javascript buffer as a file from node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, download, buffer

I have html webpage with javascript script that uses XMLHttpRequest to get a file from a server. I want a browser to open a standard "download file" window, so a user can save a file.
The code for that is simple:

```
var xhr;
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
    alert("File successfully received");
    }
  } 
xhr.open("GET”,”http://localhost:17001/filedl?param=1",true);
xhr.send();
```

On a server, I have a running node.js app with express module. 
The app is generating a buffer data and sending it back to the client as a file.
The code is here:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/filedl', function(req, res){
  var pngBuffer = new Buffer("generated png goes here");
  res.setHeader('Content-Description','File Transfer');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=print.png');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
  res.end(pngBuffer);
});
app.listen(17001);
```

However, I can't get a "Save As" dialog open up in a browser. I'm just getting a response from my server with a buffer in a text form.

I've tried setting different response http headers, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
var blobObject = new Blob([xhr.respomse], {type: 'image/png'}); 
navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, "print.png");
blobObject.msClose();
```

I'm using navigator.msSaveBlob function on client side to save a file in Internet Explorer, hope that works for you

Comment: I'm looking for a universal way to save sent data as a file. I guess I have to add or change some response headers, so the save file dialog is invoked in any browser. I believe this task can be solved without IE10-specific javascript methods.

Comment: The easist way is just create a hidden iframe element that targets the download file. if you don't need to process the data after receiving it, you can try that.

Comment: And if you change the ms prefix to webkit or moz, I believe it will work on other browsers as well.